# ideal hash code implementation

Tags: java, eclipse, equals, hashcode

I have class as following

```
public class Hash {
    int age;
    int id;
    String name;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Hash other = (Hash) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

in this I have used only two attributes name and id to generate .equals method but now my question is. what should be a good way to implement .hashCode() method.

1. Using only name and id
2. Using all three name, age and id.

what are the advantages and disadvantages of both ?

Comment: Don’t use `getClass() != obj.getClass()`. Use `instanceof`. Otherwise it breaks when you have subclasses. If you don’t want subclasses make the class `final`. But even then there’s no reason to use something else than `instanceof`.

Comment: There’s no such thing than an “ideal hash code implementation”. But your code looks sufficient. Your `hashCode` implementation has to be consistent with `equals`. Since both don’t use `age`, it’s correct.

Comment: @Holger how would it break in the case of subclasses ?. Rarely would you consider instances of two different subclasses equal. I would say you should never do that

Comment: @Dev Blanked: If you never want subclasses, make the class `final`. Otherwise you have to think about the contract of `equals` for subclasses. Look at the `equals` implementation of `AbstractList` for an example. There might be tons of different subclasses considered equal.

Comment: @Holger AbstractList scenario is a bit especial since it's implementing an interface. Therefore checking instanceof makes perfect sense. But in this case comparing classes is the correct thing to do. If you have subclasses HashA, HashB extending Hash class. You never want an instance of HashA to be considered equal to an instance of HashB

Comment: @Dev Blanked: To summarize it, `instanceof` does always the right thing while comparing class references *might* work in some cases. So what’s the reason to compare class references instead of using the language construct that is intended for this purpose? The question whether HashA ought to be considered equal to an instance of HashB cannot answered without a real use case. Another real-life example is `Ellipse2D` where instances of `Ellipse2D.Double` might be equal to `Ellipse2D.Float` instances. I could find more but I doubt that you will find a counter-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An important rule for calculating hashcode is that you must *only* use information that's also relevant for the `equals()` implementation.

Since you don't use `age` in your `equals` method, it would be wrong to use it in your `hashCode`! The reasoning is pretty simple to follow:

- imagine two objects o1 and o2 with the attributes "id=1, age=2, name=foo" and "id=1, age=3, name=foo".
- calling `equals()` would return `true`
- calling `hashCode()` (on an implementation that uses `age`) would return two different values, however!

That does *not* mean that you *must use all* such information. Sometimes it has advantages to use just a subset (for example if there is some big, hard-to-hash object that's unlikely to be the only difference between two objects).

The most primitive, correct implementation for you would be this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
}
```

It would be *correct*, but terribly inefficient (because every object would hash to the same value, obviously!).

Comment: this means we can use information only used in .equals or a subset of that but we should not use any extra information

Comment: @ankit: exactly. You can even use the empty subset (even if it's usually a bad idea).

Comment: ok one last question is it mandatory to do so, is there any harm in using some extra info this will make our hashcode more powerful only

Comment: @ankit: if by "extra info" you mean "extra info that's used in equals as well" then the only possible drawback that I can think of is that your hash code might take longer to calculate. And depending on how exactly you use your objects that may or may not be relevant (sorry for the vague answer, but it really depends: if you rarely or ever use your object in a `HashSet` or a key in a `HashMap`, then the entire `hashCode` debate doesn't matter much at all).

Answer (score 0):

Without thinking too much i would use: apache's [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html)

To use this class write code as follows:

```
 public class Person {
   String name;
   int age;
   boolean smoker;
   ...

   public int hashCode() {
     // you pick a hard-coded, randomly chosen, non-zero, odd number
     // ideally different for each class
     return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).
       append(name).
       append(age).
       append(smoker).
       toHashCode();
   }
 }
```

**With an answer**: Does only `name` and `id` uniquely identifies each object of the Class and consistent for comparison with `equal()` ? If **yes**, then why should i use **three** attributes instead of **two**?

[Check this **Hashing it out** Article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html), a bit old but good details.

Comment: there are n number of ways to generate hashcode automatically but I want to understand the zest of the logic behind it

Comment: That implementation is wrong (even if using `HashCodeBuilder` in itself is not bad): if `equals` doesn't care about `age`, then `hashCode` must not use it!

Comment: i have added a last para with a question to answer his question. That code was just an example i picked from the linked page, it wasn't meant to be used for his answer.

Comment: @Sage +1 for your edit now it makes sense however I am not the downvoter

Comment: @ankit, sorry i replied to Joachim. Though i should have used `@` notation. Actually i was editing when you and he were commenting. I also wanted to link some article though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use only id field only to generate hashcode if your id is unique. In this way you will be able to search your object from the collection by creating object using id only.

Also if your id is unique, we will have different hash code for different objects so it will be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of hashcode method depends on how you want the bucketing to be done-

1. One may choose to put all objects of even id in one bucket and odd id in another bucket.

> ```
>     @Override
>     public int hashCode() {
>        return this.id % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2;
>     }
> ```

1. Or you can choose to put people whose age is 0-10 in one bucket, 10-20 in another and so on.

> ```
>     @Override
>     public int hashCode() {
>        return this.age / 10 ;
>     }
> ```

The point is, it really depends on how your objects are spread over in range(if the objects are properly divided in buckets, you will get better performance) and how you want to do the bucketing.